# App crashes after AppStore upgrade

Tags: ios, crash, iphone-sdk-3.1.3, iphone

I have just release a new version of my app to Apple which Apple approved. The version works great... for new users. But for "old" users the app crashes. They have to uninstall the app and then re-install it.

I have some users still running 3.1.3 which even see app crashes after unstalling and re-installing it.

This is the crash log from one of my users:

> Date/Time:       2010-11-25 17:29:00.476 +0100
>   OS Version:      iPhone OS 3.1.3 (7E18) 
>   Report Version:  104
>   
>   Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT
>   (SIGTRAP) Exception Codes: 0x00000001,
>   0xe7ffdefe Crashed Thread:  0
>   
>   Dyld Error Message:   Symbol not found: __NSConcreteGlobalBlock
>   Referenced from:
>   /var/mobile/Applications/2B003960-53A3-479A-9132-FE38C4AE88A2/stationen.app/stationen
>   Expected in:
>   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib  in
>   /var/mobile/Applications/2B003960-53A3-479A-9132-FE38C4AE88A2/stationen.app/stationen
>   Dyld Version: 149

This doesn't say me anything, can anybody help me with it?
App works great on my iPhone 4 running 4.1.

Regards,
Paul Peelen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Flurry? If so you might want to have a look at this [FAQ page](http://wiki.flurry.com/index.php?title=IPhone_FAQ).

From the page:

> To support OS 3.x, please set Base SDK
>   to iPhone Device 4.0 and iPhone OS
>   Deployment Target to iPhone OS 3.0.
>   Extra linker flags may be needed if
>   NSConcreteGlobalBlock and
>   UIBackgroundTaskInvalid runtime error
>   occur under 3.x. The linker flags are:
>   weak_framework UIKit weak_library
>   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Comment: Yes, I am using Flurry. Missed that. I do have weak UIKit linker flag, but thats because of backgrounding. Will have a look into that. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively in XCode 4 add "UIKit.framework" and "libSystem.B.dylib" in Build Phases and mark them as "Optional".

Answer (score 1):

```
Dyld Error Message: Symbol not found: __NSConcreteGlobalBlock
```

Means that you're using `__NSConcreteGlobalBlock` and that it's not found on the device.

If you're using blocks in you app, you must require iOS 4.0 at least.